# Uniform initialization in C++14 double assigned to float variable does not produce narrowing error

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

From my understanding of uniform initialization, the following code should produce a narrowing error but it does not:

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    double d;
    float f = {d}; // should produce a narrowing error
return 0;

}
```

I believe that this is an error because the compiler has to consider all possible values of d, in other words, the range of values that d can potentially hold is larger than what a float can hold.

> gcc version 4.9.3

Comment: The standard pretty much never requires anything to be treated as an error by the compiler.

Comment: @BoBTFish That's not true, the section on list-initialization (`[dcl.init.list]/3`) outlines a number of other places where narrowing conversions are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed give a warning using `g++ -std=c++11`, however not if you leave out the c++11 compiler flag (using g++ 4.9.2).

Using `clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -pedantic -Wdeprecated -Wextra` this does not compile, but gives a narrowing error instead of only a warning (using clang++ 3.6.0).

Comment: I compiled without the -std=c++14 flag resulting in no warnings or errors of any kind. I got the expected results after doing so.

Answer (score 2):

A narrowing conversion is required to emit a diagnostic.  A warning or an error satisfies that.

Running you code [here](http://goo.gl/yUbwQ2) (gcc 4.9.2 which is the closet version I can link to) emits a warning

```
warning: narrowing conversion of 'd' from 'double' to 'float' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

This satisfies the requirement imposed by the standard.

If you really want an error you can always use `-Werror` or which will treat all warnings as errors or `-pedantic-errors` which will treat the narrowing conversion as an error.

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't make a distinction between "errors" and "warnings". Your code is ill-formed, but the standard says this:

> `N4140 [intro.compliance]/2.2:` If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in
>   this Standard as “conditionally-supported”when the implementation does not support that construct,
>   a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.
>
> `[intro.compliance]/8:` A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.

GCC emits a diagnostic for the ill-formed code, so it's compliant in this respect. Note that it *will* issue an error if you pass `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0):

From the bug here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783

> The standard only requires that "a conforming implementation shall
>   issue at least one diagnostic message" so compiling the program with a
>   warning is allowed.  As Andrew said, -Werror=narrowing allows you to
>   make it an error if you want.